# Local form of Lagrangians

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, submanifold

Let $T^\star N$ be the cotangent bundle of some manifold $N$. I think it is a standard fact that, given a $1$-form $\mu$ on $N$, $\text{Graph}(\mu)$ is a Lagrangian submanifold of $T^\star N$.

My question is the following: say I have two Lagrangians $L_1$ and $L_2$ in *some symplectic manifold*, and I choose a Weinstein neighbourhood $\mathcal{U}$ of $L_1$ (so a neighbourhood in which $L_1$ locally looks like the inclusion of the zero section $L_1 \overset{0}{\hookrightarrow} T^\star L_1$)

Is it possible to find a function $f$ such that, in this neighbourhood, $L_2 = \text{Graph}(\mathrm{d}f)$? (Maybe shrinking the neighbourhood $\mathcal{U}$, if necessary?)

Comment: The first paragraph is incorrect as stated. Could you write it more precisely?

Comment: And how are $L_1$ and $L_2$ related? Your statement about $L_1$ does not mention $L_2$ and your question about $L_2$ does not mention $L_1$.

Comment: @Deane I meant it more as a general statement: "Writing my Lagrangian $L_1$ as the zero section in $T^\star L_1$, can any other Lagrangian be written (at least locally) as $\text{Graph}(df)$ for some $f$?

Comment: @Deane yes. I think the statement is true in a cotangent bundle though, isn't it? I edited the question, though if you were referring to some other issue, I may have missed it

Comment: And my second question? Why is $L_1$ needed for your question about $L_2$?

Comment: @Deane I guess I wanted to say that I was working in the cotangent bundle of a Lagrangian. Hence, my question could be reformulated as: "In the cotangent bundle of a Lagrangian, can any other Lagrangian locally be written as the graph of a (closed) $1$-form?" Though maybe the fact that I'm in the cotangent bundle of a Lagrangian, and not just any manifold, does not matter

Comment: You have to restrict your attention to particular Lagrangians, since the fibers of the cotangent bundle are also Lagrangians. Doing this, your question is more or less the nearby Lagrangian conjecture.

Comment: If you’re assuming something about $L_2$ relative to $L_1$, could you state it explicitly in the body of question?